# Can you turn on a light bulb using only one of the two wires of the wall outlet?

Tags: ac, dc, high-voltage

Instead of trying crazy things I would rather ask. I am asking this for purposes of learning.

So I have learned that if the voltage is high you can get electrocuted by touching only one side of the wall outlet. That is because the potential difference is high enough for the electrons to start flowing.

**Taking that into consideration, if I were to make this connection will the light bulb turn on?**

[image]

Will this also happen with a higher voltage 120V DC battery?

If this were to also be true with the battery this would work by connecting only the positive side of the battery, correct? If you were to touch the negative side of the battery nothing would happen, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a very tiny lightbulb that doesn't require much power at all, then yes it can work. It works because the 2nd wire from the lamp is connected by parasitic capacitance to electrical ground, completing the circuit. There's a type of testers used to check if an outlet is "hot" that work on this principle. They work best when the user touches the 2nd wire to increase the capacitance to ground.

> Will this also happen with a high 120V DC battery?

No, because a capacitive connection can only pass AC current.

> If this where to also be true with the battery this will only work by connecting the positive side of the battery correct? If you where to touch the negative side of the battery nothing will happen correct?

If you want to power a circuit from a battery you have to connect one side of the circuit to the positive terminal of the battery and the other side of the terminal to the negative terminal of the battery.

You can't power a circuit by connecting either one of the terminals on its own to the circuit.

Comment: Case in point : replacing old lampbulbs with LED or CFL, they can glow or flicker very faintly (only visible in complete darkness) when switched "off" given enough series capacitance. I've seen this in double switched lights (stair lights) where the cable between floors provided the capacitance.

Comment: "*They work best when the user touches the 2nd wire to increase the capacitance to ground.*" And these use a neon lamp with a high resistance in series so the current is only a milliamp or so. Don't try it with a filament bulb.